# Ambiences - MKH418S / Sony ECM MS5 / Rode NT4 (x/y)

Tags: microphone, microphone-technique, ms, ambience, mkh

Good morning from Prague,

today, I'm recording some stereo ambiences for a short film.
Shame on me, but I used M-S mic just once so far for a school exercise. (We had to create some layered ambiences and in the end, it went the lo-fi way because I used even my poor pal H4N when M-S mic wasn't available...)

Our humble sound department is kind of limited so I'm forced to chose between these M-S mics:
MKH418S or Sony ECM MS-5 or X/Y Rode NT4

I would chose MKH but: is it really a good choice recording ambiences with M-S?
Also: would 2 MS mics set in opposite directions help me in later 5.1 mix? What is your regular approach? And what would it be in this situation?
There's a possibility to get a pair of Beyerdynamic MC 930. Should I try it if available or is it just a silly idea?

Thanks and have a nice day,
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you read these two articles for more insight on M/S recording, which, by the way, I absolutely recommend you do:

http://designingsound.org/2013/10/charles-maynes-on-mid-side-recording/
http://designingsound.org/2014/02/la-underground-an-interview-with-charles-maynes/

And as as addendum, I would say that, so long as you have extra channels or recorders, you should record with as many different mics and/or handheld recorders as you can get your hands on. Sure, recording with a Neumann 191 to a Sound Devices 744 may be the bee's knees, but you may get *a more suitable* recording from that cheapo Zoom H2 you've got in your backpack, based on the footage that was shot or the story you're trying to convey with sound. If you've got a 6-channel recorder, then shoot with 3 different mics and make choices later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and recommendations. I've just finished reading these articles and it was very inspiring and refreshing. This morning, I used just MKH 418S and I was very disappointed. Very noisy and kind of dull sounding. I didn't have an opportunity to record into Sound Devices, just Edirol R4. Should have try to use 2 MS mics though